# IIS Express: 404 0x80070002 on D:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express-10

I have an issue running an asp.net application from D:.

If I create a new asp.net MVC project in D:\code and hit the debug button I get an IIS Express 10.0 404 page saying:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module             IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler            StaticFile
Error Code         0x80070002
```

However, if I create a similar project in C:\Users\USERNAME\Source\repos everything works as expected.

This problem started appearing 3-4 weeks ago. Prior to that, all projects ran fine from D:\code.

I'm currently running

- Visual Studio 15.8.6
- IIS Express 10.0
- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18242.1000] (Insider Preview)

My two main theories at this stage is:

1. It is related to a recent Insider build. The problem started appearing 2-3 updates ago. I've tried reverting the Windows version, but cannot revert more than one version it seems.
2. Something related to permissions. I tried adding the ISS_USERS "group" in a later attempt, but that did not work.

What I've tried so far:

- Uninstalling IIS Express 10.0
- Installing IIS Express 8.0
- Deleting appsettings.config
- Delete .vs folder
- Adding the ISS_USERS group to the folder
- Rebooting
- Reverting Windows version
- Repair Visual Studio
- Upgrade Visual Studio

These are the security settings for the project in C:\Users\USERNAME\Source\repos

[image: These are the security settings for the project in C:\Users\<username>\Source\repos]

And these are the security settings for the project in D:\code

[image: security settings for the project in D:\code]

Lastly: I am aware that everything works if I use C:\Users\USERNAME\Source\repos to store my code. However, I want this to work in D:\code as it did previously.

Comment: Based on your description, it seems to be related with permission. Could you try to check whether this issue exist when running the VS as administrator? It seems `Atle Frenvik Sveen` is your personal account, does it have full control over the `Code Folder`? If you create a new folder in `D:`, will this issue happen again?

Comment: @TaoZhou: Thank you for your suggestions.Running VS as administrator gave no result (I presume because IIS Express does not inherit admin privileges?). If I move the project from D:\code to D:\ it works fine

Comment: So I'm basically wondering: What did I do to D:\code? I ran a command to fix case  sensitivity related to WSL, I might have run some other WSL-related stuff as well

Comment: Try to create a new folder under D: and move the project to test whether it will work. If works, check the folder proeprties one by one like `Security`.

Comment: That was what I did. I Also found that running fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> disable moves things forward (a bit, now I get weird errors related to roslyn and WiewBag not beeing defined). And somewhere along the line VS has stopped beeing able to install nuget packages when I create a new MVC project

Comment: Not sure whether the root cause is import, why not delete the `code` folder, and go with your project with a new folder?

Comment: That might be the correct solution here, but my problem is that I have a lot of projects (both .net and other kinds) checked out in D:\code. Checking out all of them anew seems like a lot of work..

Comment: Again: just creating D:\code2 and copying the TestApp project there made things work as expected. I guess I'll just copy the contents of D:\code to D:\code2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Kindly go with this workaround, hope others who run into similiar issue would provide the solution for you.